# slide toggle and multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html-lists, slidetoggle

I'm having some problems with a simple slidetoggle I have to apply on multiple `<li>` elements.

Example:

```
<ul id="serv">
    <li id="01">Assistenza</li>
    <li id="02">Riparazione</li>
    <li id="03">Manutenzione</li>
    <li id="04">Rifacimento Macchina</li>
</ul>

<div id="box01"></div>
<div id="box02"></div>
<div id="box03"></div>
<div id="box04"></div>
```

now I just simply want when I click on 01 box01 shows, 02 box02 shows.. etc
So..

```
 <script>
  $('#01').click(function() {
    $('#box01').slideToggle()
  })
</script>
```

In this case I should have to repeat this for every single id.. And if I have many elements? Is there a way to simplify this process so that I "write less and do more"?

Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Comment: there's an error in the script #01 replaces .slidetoggle and #box01 .box01.. I cannot modify the post..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('#box'+$(this).attr('id')).slideToggle()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vwDn6/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="serv">
    <li class="toggler" id="01">Assistenza</li>
    <li class="toggler" id="02">Riparazione</li>
    <li class="toggler" id="03">Manutenzione</li>
    <li class="toggler" id="04">Rifacimento Macchina</li>
</ul>

$('.toggler').click(function() {
    $('#box' + $(this).attr('id')).slideToggle()
}
```

To add accordion functionality:

```
$('.toggler').click(function() {
    $('li').slideUp();
    $('#box' + $(this).attr('id')).slideToggle()
}
```

Comment: just another question.. And if I'd want to exclude others li to be opened when another box is open?

Comment: Then you'd add a line to close all LIs first. See my edited answer.

Comment: I told it bad.. Sorry.. not the li but the the #box1.. if I click on li 01 box01 appears.. but if I click on li 02 box02 appears below box01 and this doesn't slide up. I meant a simple exclusion between boxes. Thanx again